# FuelPHP form field value converts some character into HTML entities

Tags: forms, encoding, html-entities, fuelphp

I have strange behavior in FuelPHP. I generate form field with FuelPHP Form::input() method. The problem is that some characters get converted into HTML entities. For example character `š` gets converted into `&scaron;`. The form field generation code can be seen below and the output can be seen on the picture (the first output is just the plain html text).

```
<?php echo $user->profile_fields['firstname']; ?> 
<?php echo Form::input('firstname', Input::post('firstname', isset($user->profile_fields['firstname']) ? $user->profile_fields['firstname'] : '')); ?>
```

[image]

The weirdest thing is this only happens in the form field where the value is read from `profile_fields` DB field in user table (`$user->profile_fields['firstname']`). `Profile_fields` is standard MySQL text field in user table used by SimpleAuth driver. This field holds serialized key=>value pairs of user information like firstname, lastname, address and so on... If I read the same value from non-serialized field in DB and create form field with this value then it will be displayed properly.

I use `utf8_unicode_ci` collation and encoding in my DB setup, and FuelPHP locale and encoding is also set properly to `UTF-8`.

UPDATE1:
take a look at this:

```
//values read from MySQL DB, via FuelPHP orm, unserialized
echo $user->profile_fields['firstname'] . ' ' . $user->profile_fields['lastname'];
echo '<br>';

//same values serialized and assigned to PHP array var
$test = serialize(array('firstname'=>'Urška', 'lastname'=>'Neumüller'));
var_dump($test);

echo '<br>';
$test2 = unserialize($test);
var_dump($test2);

echo '<br>';
echo '<input type="text" value="'.$test2['firstname'].'">';
echo '<input type="text" value="'.$test2['lastname'].'">';

echo '<br>';
echo '<input type="text" value="'.htmlspecialchars($test2['firstname']).'">';
echo '<input type="text" value="'.htmlspecialchars($test2['lastname']).'">';

echo '<br>';
echo '<input type="text" value="'.$user->profile_fields['firstname'].'">';
echo '<input type="text" value="'.$user->profile_fields['lastname'].'">';

echo '<br>';
echo '<input type="text" value="'.htmlspecialchars($user->profile_fields['firstname']).'">';
echo '<input type="text" value="'.htmlspecialchars($user->profile_fields['lastname']).'">';
```

`htmlspecialchars` is used here because FuelPHP Form class use it when generating a form field and is the cause for some characters being converted into HTML entities.

output:

[image]

Is this problem in DB, PHP, FuelPHP... I am completely lost here!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to look very clearly at what you are doing.

FuelPHP by default encodes on output, meaning all data you send to a view will be html encoded. In this case, $user, which is send from the controller to the view, will be encoded.

Your $test2 array is created INSIDE the view, and will therefore not be encoded.

Now, when you use a value of $user in Form::input(), the value will be prepped (as Frank correctly mentioned), which will encode again. As an example, "&amp;" will be converted to "&amp;amp;", and will lead to the behaviour you describe. Same if you manually encode a value from $user, as your example shows.

So:

- pass the variable to the view without encoding (might be dangerous!)
- disable prepping as Frank described
- upgrade to the latest 1.1/develop branch, which has double encoding disabled by default

Answer (score 0):

Normally special characters are encoded on output, for security reasons. You can turn that off if you set the form condig param `prep_value` to `false` or supply the input field an attr of `"dont_prep" => true`.

Comment: yes I know that, but for all other forms where I read the values from Database from non-serialized fields, then they display OK and I don't have this issue. It's only the issue when reading and setting form values from a user table profile_fields field, where data is being serialized!